# How to pass generic parameter though NavLink in Blazor?

Tags: c#, generics, blazor

I have a generic component that expects a generic type parameter to be passed. Componenet is as follows:

```
@page "/topicgrid"
@typeparam TDataModel
<h1>Title</h1>
```

The code-behind class is as follows:

```
public partial class TopicGrid<TDataModel> : ComponentBase
{
}
```

I can use this component as follows:

```
<TopicGrid TDataModel="SomeTopicModel" /> // SomeTopicModel is a class
```

However, I need to create this component through the NavLink component. NavLink only wants to know the route of the component, nothing else. How could I achieve this?

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" href="topicgrid">
    Topic Grid
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest your generic component inside another component whose job is to initialize the parameters that you need to pass.

```
@page “/topicgrid”
<TopicGrid .../>
```